# how do I connect with salesforce with python requests?

Tags: python, salesforce

Traceback error while connecting with salesforce API: [{'message': 'INVALID_HEADER_TYPE', 'errorCode': 'INVALID_AUTH_HEADER'}]

What is the problem?

My python codes are as follows:

```
client_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
client_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
redirect_url = 'http://localhost/'
cm_user = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
cm_pass = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

auth_url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token'

response = requests.post(auth_url, data = {
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'grant_type':'password',
    'username': cm_user,
    'password': cm_pass
})

json_res = response.json()
access_token = json_res['access_token']
auth = {'Authorization': 'Bearer' + access_token}

instance_url = json_res['instance_url']

url = instance_url + '/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/contact/describe'
res = requests.get(url, headers=auth)
r = res.json()
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space after the word Bearer, which renders your authorization header invalid.